# Using pyxl to determine range of merged cell in excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a large excel file where column B is composed of variably sized merged cells. I need to access the adjacent cells in column C but only the ones that are encompassed by the range of the merged cell to their left. Is it possible to identify the range of a single specific cell?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I've been trying to work something out using .merged_cell_ranges or .merged_cell but these both seem to display all merged cells within the worksheet. I know the specific location of the cell I want but I can't determine the range that it covers

Comment: Please include a small sample of the code you're using.